# Как разделить код ViewModel-ей на каждое окно?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wcf, mvvm

Я пишу WCF-сервис. Он создается в MainViewModel. Остальные ViewModel-и никак не могут получить его объект. Как же мне разделить? А то получается что для всех окон одна ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

1. Сделайте у всех ваших VM сервис параметром конструктора
2. Создайте сервис в `App.OnStartup`, там же создавайте ваши VM, и передавайте в конструктор.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39910/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd----viewmodel----).